# How to connect mysql database and Sybase Database in one connection string in Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, sybase, dbi

I have connected both database, but used two connection string. Is there any possible to connect by using one connection string for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Perl, the DBI architecture is split into 2 main groups of software : DBI itself and the Drivers(DBD). Each RDBMS has its own driver in Perl, and each driver has a connection string linked to it. You cannot make a "unified" connection string.